# Multiple Webservice Test Mock

Tags: unit-test, webservices, webservicemock

I have a method that calls multiple webservices in it.

When I implement a mock webservice how does it tie that mock webservice to the actual web service it is mocking?

Is it possible to create multiple mock webservices in a class so each webservice callout will use the corresponding mock webservice?

[This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) is what I'm working from.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into mocking the responses using [`MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_multistaticresourcecalloutmock.htm). It is designed to be a mechanism to provide different responses based on the URL that is requested during the test.

Essentially you reference a Static Resource which includes your various response payloads and you associate them to the URL that you're going to be making calls out to.

When your code calls the given URL, the `MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock` will respond with the payload from the Static Resource.

[Related documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm)